# Can I programmatically login a user without a password?

Tags: login, authentication

I'm manually creating users programmatically, and I want to sign in the newly created user. WP makes it easy to access the hashed password, but not the plaintext version. Is there a way to use wp_signon() without the plaintext password?

I found one person who claims to have done this [here](http://www.ashishdubey.info/blog/custom-authentication-for-wordpress-users), but it didn't work for me.

THANKS!

Comment: I think you can just assign the user object of the user you just created to the current_user global variable

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[`wp_set_auth_cookie()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie) will log a user in without having to know their password.

Comment: This worked great. However, when I use it, the conditional `is_user_logged_in()` doesn't seem to work. Do you know if it's looking at something different than the cookies?

Comment: @Emerson - what hook are you logging them in on? it has to be before headers are sent. also try to [`wp_set_current_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user) before logging them in.

Comment: I actually wasn't calling it from a hook at all. I just added `wp_set_auth_cookie()` into my signin function. I guess I need to rethink that. I'll also lookup wp_set_current_user and report back. Thank you very much for your help on this!

Comment: Well, is it possible to login a user without having his details exist in database? Just setting few cookies in browser through script is enough? Please let me know.

Answer (score 66):

The following code does the job for automatic login, without any password!

```
// Automatic login //
$username = "Admin";
$user = get_user_by('login', $username );

// Redirect URL //
if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) )
{
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
    wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );

    $redirect_to = user_admin_url();
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Well, it works great. Just the username is enough, which is case insensitive.

Comment: `get_user_by()` returns false on failure, so you should check for false instead of the WP_Error object

Comment: @Sjoerd Linders, where can I hook your script in order to force a user to be connected?

Comment: Where do I keep this block of code in which file?

Answer (score 15):

I have found another solution [here](https://iandunn.name/programmatically-sign-on-a-wordpress-user/) that uses a better approach (at least in my opinion...).
No need to set any cookie, it uses the Wordpress API:

```
/**
 * Programmatically logs a user in
 * 
 * @param string $username
 * @return bool True if the login was successful; false if it wasn't
 */
    function programmatic_login( $username ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            wp_logout();
        }

    add_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );    // hook in earlier than other callbacks to short-circuit them
    $user = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $username ) );
    remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );

    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
 }

 /**
  * An 'authenticate' filter callback that authenticates the user using only     the username.
  *
  * To avoid potential security vulnerabilities, this should only be used in     the context of a programmatic login,
  * and unhooked immediately after it fires.
  * 
  * @param WP_User $user
  * @param string $username
  * @param string $password
  * @return bool|WP_User a WP_User object if the username matched an existing user, or false if it didn't
  */
 function allow_programmatic_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
    return get_user_by( 'login', $username );
 }
```

I think the code is self explanatory:

The filter searches for the WP_User object for the given username and returns it.
A call to the function `wp_set_current_user` with the WP_User object returned by `wp_signon`, a check with the function `is_user_logged_in` to make sure your are logged in, and that's it!

A nice and clean piece of code in my opinion!

Comment: where to use programmatic_login?

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: @Shebo Your comment doesn't seem to be correct. The first line of the function checks whether the array `$credentials` is empty or not. If the array is not empty (which is the case in my answer), the values from the array are used to authenticate the user.

Comment: @Mike wow, how do I missed it... My bad, sorry for misleading. I'll delete my first comment, to avoid confusion. Great solution though :)

Comment: It might be worthwhile to enclose `wp_signon()` in a try block and call `remove_filter` in the finally block. This should ensure that the filter is always removed.

Answer (score 8):

This works well for me:

```
  clean_user_cache($user->ID);
  wp_clear_auth_cookie();
  wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
  wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, false);
  update_user_caches($user);
```

Comment: This nice articles provides explanation on why this is necessary: https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-user-caches/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Mike, Paul and Sjoerd:

To better handle `login.php` redirections:

```
//---------------------Automatic login--------------------

if(!is_user_logged_in()){

    $username = "user1";

    if($user=get_user_by('login',$username)){

        clean_user_cache($user->ID);

        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID , true, false);

        update_user_caches($user);

        if(is_user_logged_in()){

            $redirect_to = user_admin_url();
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
elseif('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == wp_login_url()){

    $redirect_to = user_admin_url();
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
    exit;
}
```

To be placed in `wp-config.php` just after

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

**FYI**

Based on the above solution, I have released a plugin to keep the user logged in from one wordpress to another by synchronizing user data and cookie session:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-session-synchronizer/

Answer (score 1):

Strange enough but the only way it works for me is if I redirect and die() after:

```
clean_user_cache($user->ID);
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true, true );
update_user_caches( $user );

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $redirect_to = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("location:".$redirect_to );
    die(); 

}
```

Comment: You can set the  $redirect_to var to any existing page in you site. Eg:  `$redirect_to = site_url();`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is true way. We should clear user cache and cookies. After logged in, we need to trigger `wp_login` hook to work other plugins and core functions together.

```
$user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id ); // Get WP_User from user ID.
// $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email ); // Or Get from email.
// $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username ); // Or get from username.

if ( false !== $user ) {
    clean_user_cache( $user->ID );
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
    update_user_caches( $user );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login, $user );
}
```