# Login with serialized password

Tags: login, remote-login

I can manually log in an user by doing

```
wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $user, 'user_password' => $pass ) );
```

But the password must be in plain text, is there a way to log in with the already hashed password instead of plain text?

Edit: It's not like I want to login without a password, I just want to use a hashed password instead of a plain text one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I programmatically login a user without a password?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password)

Comment: So do you have access to the plaintext password, or you have access to the already-hashed password?

Comment: You will have to be more specific in what your problem is and what solution you are aiming for. Please explain **why** you want to do it that way. It could be that you are facing a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @kaiser because sending a plain text password can be read by man in the middle attacks. go to a coffee shop and login to a http wordpress site. anyone there on their network can see it in real time. then once they have your login they can attempt to use it at other sites.

Comment: That's what HTTPS (over SSL, over TCP) is for: It encrypts your users data.