# How do I get WordPress login to ignore the password input if a particular username is used?

Tags: database, login, password, authentication

I am trying to build a login where users with an account number as their username can login without a password or email.

When the user clicks login, if the username that has been input exists in the database and starts with a zero (Because I plan to make all these special accounts account numbers like 0612345), then WordPress shouldn’t bother to authenticate the password and should let the user into the account that matches that username.

I have no PHP experience but have tried to piece together code from other people's questions:

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'allow_certain_users', 9999, 3);
function allow_certain_users( $user, $username, $password) {
    // If the username starts with a zero, ignore whether the password input is correct
    if (substr($username, 0, 1) == "0") {
        $user = apply_filters('authenticate', null, $username, $password);
        return $user;
    }
    return $user;
}
```

To explain why, these account number users will have minimal capabilities so there won't be anything critical or personal that needs securing within each account. I would just like to avoid having to deal with the personal data of emails and passwords.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: hmmm, WP users still need an email, how are you planning to avoid that hard requirement? Note that this will have security consequences for your site, even with limited abilities for those users, and this does not sidestep GDPR and other data regulations around personal data

Comment: @TomJNowell Basically by using nonsense emails the user will never see or need to have anything to do with. What personal data issues do you think only having an account number will cause?

Comment: Anything your users have attached to them basically, including the identifier itself

Comment: Sorry, do you mean cookies? The account number won't be used anywhere else except for a spreadsheet where each user can be identified for support.

Comment: Then that account ID is personally identifying information, because it can be used to identify a person ( via a spreadsheet at support )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wp_create_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/) function to create users without a defined email

To log in without a password you can see [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password)